# Perl autosplit inside quotes

Tags: perl

I tried to print my apache2 access log dates with the following one liner. Within single quotes it shows the value but within double quotes it shows as Array object. My command is as follows

```
sudo perl -ane 'print $F[3] . "\n" ' /var/log/apache2/access.log | head -n 10
```

**Output**

```
[21/Jul/2014:09:16:05
[21/Jul/2014:09:16:05
[21/Jul/2014:11:32:55
[21/Jul/2014:11:32:55
[21/Jul/2014:11:32:59
[21/Jul/2014:11:33:02
[21/Jul/2014:11:33:02
[21/Jul/2014:11:33:10
[21/Jul/2014:11:33:14
[21/Jul/2014:11:33:14

sudo perl -ane "print $F[3] . \"\n\" " /var/log/apache2/access.log | head -n 10
```

**output**

```
ARRAY(0x195fca8)
ARRAY(0x1960128)
ARRAY(0x195fca8)
ARRAY(0x195fd38)
ARRAY(0x1960128)
ARRAY(0x195fca8)
ARRAY(0x195fd38)
ARRAY(0x1960128)
ARRAY(0x195fca8)
ARRAY(0x195fd38)
```

When I try to dereference the array it shows one.

```
sudo perl -ane "print @{$F[3]} . \"\n\" " /var/log/apache2/access.log | head -n 10
```

**output**

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I am using ubuntu 12.04 64 bit with guake terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using double quotes `$` gets interpolated by Bash and not by Perl. That's why this is happening.

Example:

```
a='foo bar'; perl -le "print \"$a\""
foo bar
```

Comment: Why is \" needed? can u explain me more plz. @Tiago

Comment: `\"` is needed because perl needs `"` but bash won't pass it to perl that's why we escape it. It could be written like this: `a='foo bar'; perl -le "print q($a)"`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `q` is the single quote operator in perl. just like `qq` is the double quote operator.